# How to specify a Tikz coordinate relative to a node?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, coordinates

is there a simple idiom (one not using the `calc` library) to specify a Tikz coordinate relative to a node?

Something like `\coordinate (x) [right=of A];` instead of  `\node (x) [draw=none, right=of A]{};`?

Thanks

Comment: Where do you want the coordinate to end up?  Nodes come equipped with a whole slew of anchors, would one of them do?  `(A.east)` seems a reasonable one in this case.

Comment: `\coordinate[right=of A]  (x) ;  `is fine  but not `\coordinate (x) [right=of A];`

Comment: @AndrewStacey The advantage of doing `[right=of A]` instead of `(A.east)`, as you suggest, is that I can change the node distance and have the coordinate repositioned, or I can say directly things like `[right=30mm of A]`. Also a coordinate has no space, that's why I had to put `[draw=none ...` above.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage {tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document} 

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A){A};
    \coordinate  (x) [right=of A];  % <-- this does *not* work expected
    \coordinate[right=of A]  (y) ;  % <-- this *works* as expected
    \draw (x) -- ++(1,1);
    \draw[red] (y) -- ++(1,1); 
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

remark the problem is similar with

```
\node  (x) {} [right= of A];
```

instead of

```
\node[right= of A]  (x) {} ;
```

but

```
\node (x) [right= of A]  {} ;
```

is valable